Incorrect "lego" in site welcome message
The site welcome message you get when not logged in says:

Welcome to Q&A for lego and building block enthusiasts

It should say

Welcome to Q&A for LEGO® building blocks enthusiasts


Wanted to post about this, and the title auto-suggestion led me here. Has this still not been fixed yet? ಠ_ಠ

Well, first attempt at this ended up making the about page look dumb. Stupid symbols.
Crosses fingers and tries again
If this doesn't work, it's gonna be LEGO(R) – all-ASCII like God intended!

@Joe: It works now (at least for browsers that handle Unicode properly - which should be most desktop browsers at any rate). Just a bit frustrated yesterday ;-)

sigh... That's a different (but related) problem. Will dig into...
